# POD's clue in response

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In the Kubernetes cluster, I have a DEPLOYMENT with ‍`replicas: 3`

After calling the DEPLOYMENT's LoadBalancer SERVICE using `curl‍` or whatever

How do I know which POD has responded to me?

Comment: Check the pods' logs may be?

Comment: Thank you very much Sebin, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebin pointed out

By checking the logs of each POD, we can find the source of the response